# Unable to connect to mysql from sts

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

I have provided the credentials in `application.properties` to connect to Mysql but `spring-boot` is failing to take those credentials.

This is my application.properties file:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/person_example
spring.datasource.data-username=root
spring.datasource.data-password=password
```

the error shown in console:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See docs on common speinh properties here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

You need to use spring.datasource.username and spring.datasource.password

Comment: need one more help when i use -> spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none i am getting Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'person_example.person' doesn't exist                                                                                                                      i am using schema and data.sql files for data but its failing to create a table